# Problema con control de versiones en Rstudio

Tags: git, git-commit, control-de-versiones

Tengo mi proyecto de **Rstudio con el control de versiones en github**. Y hoy he ido haciendo varias modificaciones desde Rstudio con la intención de que se subiera automáticamente en el repositorio de github. Sin embargo, he ido pinchando en "commit" pero he olvidado pulsar en push (flecha verde hacia arriba) para que se efectúen los cambios en el git. El caso es que ahora no sé como puedo volver a trabajar en Rstudio y que los cambios se hagan en el repositorio, ya que cuando hago un nuevo push me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
To https://github.com/Perfydio/Proyecto_TFG
 ! [rejected]        HEAD -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Perfydio/Proyecto_TFG'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Y a parte, en la ventana de entorno de trabajo de Rstudio (arriba a la derecha) cuando pincho en la pestaña de git me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> (i) Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.

Para poder emplear el control de versiones en git a través de Rstudio simplemente seguí unos pasos que me indicaban en un curso que realicé, sin entender muy bien lo que hacía, así que no tengo ni idea de si tengo que ejecutar algun comando en la aplicación de git, cosa que he intentado sin tener éxito. Me estoy planteando crear un nuevo repositorio y un nuevo proyecto en Rstudio y empezar el control de versiones desde cero, aunque creo que quizá colgando esta pregunta aprenda algo más sobre el control de versiones y solucione el problema de manera más eficaz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que tu repositorio en github y tu repositorio local difieren debido a que olvidaste de ir haciendo los push. Tal y como te indica en uno de los errores, deberías hacer un git pull para fusionar las dos versiones.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge
Esta es la documentación oficial del git para hacer un merge. Primero deberias hacer un git pull para bajarte si hubiera cambios en el repositorio de GitHub y después fusionarlos con un git merge.

Aún así, si no has trabajado mucho con los comandos de Git, quizá la opción mas recomendable sea borrar este repositorio y crear uno de nuevo. Te recomendaria la documentación de Git.

https://git-scm.com/doc

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo hacer un git pull? Cuando ejecuto `git pull` en la aplicación de git, me aparece el siguiente mensaje: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. Este está siendo prácticamente mi primer trabajo con los comandos de Git, así que si responderme a esto es demasiado tedioso, optaré por crear un nuevo repositorio.

Comment: Para ejecutar el git pull, debes estar en la carpeta del proyecto que estas trabajando donde tienes creado tu repositorio, si es la primera vez que trabajas con Git y con los directorios, te recomendaria que te leyeras la documentación oficial de Git, o que buscaras algun tutorial explicativo quizás en youtube. Si lo ves complicado, opta por crear un nuevo repositorio. Saludos

Comment: Finalmente he optado por crear un nuevo repositorio, espero no volver a olvidarme de darle al push! Gracias.